# Most pythonic way of checking if a form submiited has data

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm currently learning Django however I'm torn on how to structure the equivalent of add method using it. I'm creating a URL shortener and I'm between the following methods to implement in creating the shortened URL:

```
def shorten(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    http_url = request.POST.get("http_url","")

    if http_url: # test if not blank
        short_id = get_short_code()
        new_url = Urls(http_url=http_url, short_id=short_id)
        new_url.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_shortener:index'))
    else:
        error_message = "You didn't provide a valid url"
        return render(request, 'url_shortener/shorten.html', { 'error_message' : error_message })

return render(request, 'url_shortener/shorten.html')
```

vs.

```
def shorten(request):
    http_url = request.POST["http_url"]
    if http_url:
        short_id = get_short_code()
        new_url = Urls(http_url=http_url, short_id=short_id)
        new_url.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_shortener:index'))

    else:
        error_message = "You didn't provide a valid url"
        return render(request, 'url_shortener/shorten.html', { 'error_message' : error_message })

    return render(request, 'url_shortener/shorten.html')
```

Specifically, I want to know the best practice on the following:

1. Is it best practice to explicity test if method is post or `http_url = request.POST["http_url"]` is enough
2. Is `http_url = request.POST.get("http_url","")` recommended to be used or this is just suppressing the error?
3. If (2) is not recommended, how can I make the `http_url` required and throw an error? I also tried the following but the except block is not triggered when I submit a blank form

   ```
   def shorten(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
           try:
               http_url = request.POST["http_url"]
               short_id = get_short_code()
               new_url = Urls(http_url=http_url, short_id=short_id)
               new_url.save()

               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_shortener:index'))
           except KeyError:
               error_message = "You didn't provide a valid url"
               return render(request, 'url_shortener/shorten.html', { 'error_message' : error_message })

       return render(request, 'url_shortener/shorten.html')
   ```

Comment: Use CBV https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Comment: Django has a whole forms framework that is meant for **exactly** this. You should be using it.

Comment: Yeah, I think the class-based views are appropriate for this but I decided to stick to the `request.POST.get("key")` for simplicity. I'll think of much complex project to implement the CBV. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
request.POST["key"]
```

will throw a `KeyError` when the `key` is not present in the dictionary. You can use a `try...catch` clause to handle the error.

Generally though, its idiomatic and perfectly normal to do:

```
request.POST.get("key")
```

More about get [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Comment: Thanks! I decided to stick with the `request.POST.get("key")` since this is just a simple project. I'll implement the class based views once I have a much complex project to work with :)